# Unallocated memory, ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I have 4 partitions and 106Gb unallocated. I try to install Windows on 106Gb Free Space. but While installing, I got that 2 partiotions got unallocated. How can I recover them??
[image]

result of quick scan with test disk:

```
Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63

The harddisk (1000 GB / 931 GiB) seems too small! (< 22 TB / 20 TiB)
Check the harddisk size: HD jumpers settings, BIOS detection...

The following partition can't be recovered:
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>  Linux Swap           12449 132 28 2697543 159 48 43136036832



[ Continue ]
SWAP2 version 3147161575, pagesize=8192, 22 TB / 20 TiB
```

and also

```
Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>* Linux                    0  32 33 12449 132 35  199999488
 P Linux Swap           12449 132 36 13694  97 35   19998720
 P HPFS - NTFS          13694 130  5 32089 105 16  295514112
 L HPFS - NTFS          32089 137 49 44837 191 26  204800000
 L HPFS - NTFS          44837 223 59 70947  59 24  419446784
 L HPFS - NTFS          70947  91 57 107747 157 58  591196160
 L FAT16 >32M           107747 190 28 117776 162 18  161114112
```

result of fdisk -l

```
Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048  200001533  199999486  95.4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2        200001534 1953519615 1753518082 836.1G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5        720320512 1139767295  419446784   200G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       1139769344 1730965503  591196160 281.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       1730967552 1892081663  161114112  76.8G  6 FAT16

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```